Looker Data Studio Stacked Bar Chart - Bar Length
Is it possible to adjust the length of each bar in my stacked bar chart to equal the same length in Looker Data Studio? I want the different metrics to be depicted by size within the bar, while also ensuring the bars are all the same length.  Thank you!
I've tried using a 100% stacked chart but it doesn't work because I want the values to be displayed as numbers not precents.
